# use jQuery to append div in frame nested in frame

Tags: jquery, append, frame

I have a page with nested frames like this:

```js
var wndSCORM2004StageFrame = jQuery('frame[name="wndSCORM2004Stage"]');
console.log(wndSCORM2004StageFrame);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<frameset rows="0,*" onload="init()" border="0">
      <frame id="wndToolBar" name="wndToolBar" src="about:blank" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" noresize border="0"/>
      <frameset cols="20,80" border="0">
        <frame id="wndLog" name="wndLog" src="about:blank" marginwidth="0" noresize border="0"/>
       <frame id="wndSCORM2004Stage" name="wndSCORM2004Stage" src="about:blank" border="0">
      </frameset>
    </frameset>
```

I can get rid of these frames as it is legacy code I am not in charge of

As you can see, the frame "wndSCORM2004Stage" is initiated with "about: blank", and there is some javascript code which loads actual content into it.

Currently, when I log the content of jQuery('frame[name="wndSCORM2004Stage"]'), I get this:

[image]

From the main page, I need to append some HTML divs in a frame which is within the frame with id "wndSCORM2004Stage".

So I probably need to wait for the content to be loaded into the frame. Correct? If this is correct, how do I check in JQuery the frame "wndSCORM2004Stage" is fully loaded and I can then select dynamically created frames within this frame?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('frame[name="wndSCORM2004Stage"]').append([YOUR HTML]);
```

or

```
$("#wndSCORM2004Stage").append([YOUR HTML]);
```

Comment: Thanks Iman, I have updated my question since the description was incomplete.
Please advise.